# Predator generator 6500 watt

Tags: generator

I have a 6500 watt predator generator, here lately every time I run it, after it runs for maybe 20 minutes to 1 hour the lights in our home cut out and then back in.

At first it was only doing it for a few seconds, but now when they cut out they stay out a few minutes before cutting back on.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could the inverter be overheating? You might want to clean out any air flow ports it has.

Comment: I agree sounds like a heat issue, is it 6500w continuous or peak and what is the total load would be my follow up question

Comment: Is it still under warranty? Take it back to horror fright. (And if your needs are mission critical enough, consider a different unit.)